# PHP variable output shows only first word out of two or more words

Tags: php, csv

Following is PHP code snippet which is being used to assign file name to the CSV file which is being generated with the set of some data.

```
if($country != '') {
    $filename .= strtolower($country);
}
```

In my MySQL database, I have a country name as: United Kingdom

The file name which appears as a result is: united.csv

Actually it has to be: united-kingdom.csv or unitedkingdom.csv

Please advice.

Comment: `strtolower()` should not do that. Are you sure $country is what you think it is?

Comment: The code shown in the question does not produce this behavior.

Comment: Yes $country is what it pulls country records.

Comment: So if you do echo $country before the if() it will echo Uinited Kingdom?

Comment: David, this is only  code snippet out of total code which assigns country name.

Comment: But in my and Davids opinion, this code is irrelevant as it does nothing like you explain.

Comment: Well that code will not generate `united-kingdon.csv` from a string with `United Kingdom` in it anyway. Show more code and the result of `echo $country` done before your IF

Comment: @Chandrakant: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/k4dm-tb0j  The code here demonstrably works as designed.  If you have code which actually produces the behavior you describe, we can help with that.  As it stands, your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

Replacing: strtolower($country);

with: strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$country));

have resolved my issue.

The string replace will find if there is a blank space (" ") between 'united' and 'states' and if there is a blank space, it will replace that blank space with hyphen ("-") making it as united-states